# $rows returning null after trying second query php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to fill 2 dropdowns from database, so I try to make one query and fill the first dropdown and then trying to make the second and fill the last dropdown.

It returns the second $rows as false but first is ok, what am I doing wrong?

```
<?php 
  $db = new Db();     
  $rows = $db -> select("call Store1(0,0);");
  var_dump($rows);  
  $rows = $db -> select("call Store1(0,0);");           
  var_dump($rows);
?>
```

These are my 2 functions:

```
public function select($query) { 
 $rows = array();
 $result = $this -> query($query);
 if($result === false)
 {
   return false;
 }
 while ($row = $result -> fetch_assoc())
 {
   $rows[] = $row;
 }
 return $rows; 
} 


public function query($query) {
  $connection = $this -> connect();
  $result = $connection -> query($query); 
  return $result; 
}
```

Comment: Before anyone can help you in a meaningful way, you need to provide the following. The definitions for the two stored procedures (at least the second), the relevant schema/sample data from which the SPs pull, the expected result, the actual/current result, and any errors you're receiving.

Comment: I can't believe there's a vote to undelete here https://stackoverflow.com/a/49819540/ being questions to the OP and flagged as "not an answer" and deleted. Now that is just too funny and baffling.

Comment: democracy mate.

Answer (score 0):

My guess (and this is just a guess...)

The first resultset (cursor) is still open. The cursor hasn't been closed. (Myabe there are more rows remaining in the current resultset which haven't been fetched yet. Or haven't been discarded by issuing a close.

And an attempt to prepare (execute) a second statement (on that same database connection) is causing an error.

(Agian, this is just a guess, by no means an actual diagnosis of the problem.)

---

My recommendation would be that we enable *error reporting*. If a SQL statement execution is returning FALSE, then we need to retrieve the error code and error message from the database. Or consider enabling PDO exceptions, so that errors are thrown so we can see them. (Something similar is probably available using mysqli.)

The return of FALSE is telling us that an error occurred, but it doesn't tell us *what* the error *is*. (And without that, it's going to be very difficult to know what to fix.)

In some cases, it may be that we don't care what the error is. In this case, it's pretty clear that we do care. And it's our job to find out what the error is... without diagnosing the root cause of the error, any attempt at writing a prescription is going to be a "try this" and "try that" shooting in the dark without aiming, hoping to hit something.

---

Recommended reading:

https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/